# Re-appearing folder in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, folders

At some point in the past, I had a folder on my desktop that I placed temporary music files off of my Aunt's iPod. I imported the files from her old school iPod in order to add to her iTunes library and import to her iPhone.

This specific path to the folder was `~/Desktop/Jean`.

I deleted this folder and emptied the trash, but 9 times out of 10, after I login after restarting my computer, the folder named Jean has reappeared on my desktop. I have no idea why this would be the case, what would be causing it, or how to make it stop occurring.

Anybody know?

info: I am running OSX 10.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the cause of my issue. I have the application PhotoSync, which was configured to sync to that particular folder. On startup it was checking that the folder existed, and when it didn't, it was creating it. Changed the default location, and its all good now. Thanks for the help guys, I +1ed everybody's response.

Answer (score 3):

Did you use an application to get those files off the iPod? If so, did that application create a folder to export the files to?

Comment: No. I bride the contents of the iPod an dragged the music to the folder. I may have salvaged something of of her iPhone as well but I don't recall. If I did it would have been with iPhone Explorer http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/

Comment: oops... typo: bride = dragged*

Answer (score 3):

BE VERY CAREFUL in following my instructions as below.  There is potential for seriously screwing up your system if anything gets mis-typed.  Which implies the following:  backup before you do any of this!

Empty your trash, then open a terminal session (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app), and very carefully, type the following:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop/Jean
```

Then:

```
cd ~/.Trash/
ls -al
```

(If you get any output, then these are the things that are in your trash.)

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

And restart.  Let us know if the folder comes back.  The rm command removes stuff, the -rf flags indicate a forced removal (f) and recursive, in order to remove folders (r).